# Max Number of Functions in a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I attempt to add a few formatting functions to the formula below I receive an error message stating you have entered too many arguments for this function, but i'm merely attempting to add a text function for formatting purposes, which simply has two arguments.  Not sure why it's throwing that error.  Is there a max number of functions you can input into a single cell?  Formula below.

P.S. I tried to put it into a code box, but it just ran on in one continuous string so this is probably better.

**Purpose of Formula:** This formula is meant to generate chat messages based upon data filled in by the user ranging from columns A-Q.  The data occurs in rows and would not be viable for a vlookup imo.  It would print out a statement like this "You Buy 100/kbbl WTI American V15 40.00 Call @ 1.00, You Sell 30/kbbl WTI V15 futures @ 41.00; ClearPort BLOCK, Thank you"  This sentence appears in Column S of each corresponding row filled in.

The length and specific diction utilized varies upon what the user inputs (hence the atrocity below).

="You "&$D21&" "&IF($A21= "NG",TEXT($E21*$G$13,"#,##0"),$E21)&IF($B21="APO","/mo ",IF($A21="NG","/MMBtu ",IF($A21="FO 3.5%","/kt ","/kbbl ")))&IF($A21="NG","Natural Gas Henry Hub",$A21)&" "&$B21&" "&$C21&" "&$F21&" "&$G21&" @ "&$H21&", "&IF(ISBLANK($K21),IF(ISBLANK($O21),"LIVE","You "&$N21&" "&IF($A21="NG",TEXT($O21*$G$13,"#,##0"),$O21)&IF($B21="APO","/mo ",IF($A21="NG","/MMBtu ",IF($A21="FO 3.5%","/kt ","/kbbl ")))&IF($A21="NG","Natural Gas Henry Hub",$A21)&" "&$C21&" "&IF($B21="American","Futures ",IF($B21="APO","Swaps ",IF($B21="European",IF($A21="NG","Penultimate Future","Swap"))))&" @ "&TEXT($P21, "#,##0.00##"),"You "&$I21&" "&IF($A21="NG",TEXT($J21*$G$13,"#,##0"),$J21)&IF($B21="APO","/mo ",IF($A21="NG","/MMBtu ",IF($A21="FO 3.5%","/kt ","/kbbl ")))&IF($A21="NG","Natural Gas Henry Hub",$A21)&" "&$B21&" "&$C21&" "&$K21&" "&$L21&" @ "&$M21&IF(ISBLANK($O21),", LIVE",", You "&$N21&" "&IF($A21="NG",TEXT($O21*$G$13,"#,##0"),$O21)&IF($B21="APO","/mo ",IF($A21="NG","/MMBtu ",IF($A21 ="FO 3.5%","/kt ","/kbbl ")))&IF($A21="NG","Natural Gas Henry Hub",$A21)&" "&$C21&" "&IF($B21="American","Futures",IF($B21="APO","Swaps",IF($B21="European",IF($A21="NG","Penultimate Future","Swap"))))&" @ "&$P21))&"; "&IF($Q21="i","ICE BLOCK,","ClearPort BLOCK,")&" Thank You"

Comment: Instead of parsing that long string it would be helpful if you showed some data in you Original post and what your expected outcome would be.

Comment: The problem is that somewhere in this nightmare of a formula, you have not set the arguments or parenthesis correctly. You'll have to inspect it with a fine-tooth-comb to find out where, or you can break up the formula into several components in several cells to make it easier to dissect. It also seems like a nice lookup table with a vlookup would serve you well here instead of all those conditional if statements.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen.  I'll break it up and walk through it.  I wish it were simpler than that, but unfortunately that's really the only way to build it out, as frustrating and nightmarish as it may seem.  The intended outcome is a confirm.  @ScottHoltzman Am I able to nest conditional statements in excel formulas like VBA?   So my false statement would be another if statement?

Comment: @StormsEdge - Yes, to your last your question. Example: `=IF(A1=1,1,IF(A1=2,2,IF(A1=3,3,"Not 1, 2, or 3")))`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks.  I have a feeling that is where the problem exists.  Perhaps a missing parenthesis or a comma that should not be.

Comment: Would a `vlookup` not be a better option? Can you let us know generally, what you're trying to do so we can make sure and avoid an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @BruceWayne See Edit above.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If ever there was an excel formula that should be migrated to a UDF, I think this is it.

Just the same, I think the complexity of the formula is causing an unbalanced parentheses error.

I have a small VBA subroutine that will break out complex formulas like this and add white space and indention. It's not perfect, but it does the job.

```
Sub beautifier()
    strCodeIn = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    indent = 1
    i = 1

    Do Until IsError(Mid(strCodeIn, i, 1))
        strChar = Mid(strCodeIn, i, 1)
        If InStr(1, "(&,", strChar) > 0 Then
            If indent = 0 Then indent = 1
            If i > Len(strCodeIn) Then Exit Do
            If InStr(1, "(", strChar) > 0 Then indent = indent + 1
            strCodeIn = Left(strCodeIn, i) & vbCrLf & String(indent, Chr(9)) & Right(strCodeIn, Len(strCodeIn) - i)
            i = i + indent
        ElseIf InStr(1, ")", strChar) > 0 Then
            If indent <> 0 Then indent = indent - 1
            strCodeIn = Left(strCodeIn, i - 1) & vbCrLf & String(indent, Chr(9)) & Right(strCodeIn, Len(strCodeIn) - (i - 1))
            i = i + indent + 3
        ElseIf i > 5000 Then Exit Do
        Else: i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
    Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
    Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
    clipboard.SetText strCodeIn
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value = strCodeIn
End Sub
```

Stick your formula in Tab `Sheet1`, Cell `A1` without the equals sign, and run the subroutine. It will stick the results in your clipboard so you can take it to a good text editor that highlights matching parentheticals like Notepad++. You'll get:

```
"You "&
    $D21&
    " "&
    IF(
        $A21= "NG",
        TEXT(
            $E21*$G$13,
            "#,
            ##0"
        ),
        $E21
    )&
    IF(
        $B21="APO",
        "/mo ",
        IF(
            $A21="NG",
            "/MMBtu ",
            IF(
                $A21="FO 3.5%",
                "/kt ",
                "/kbbl "
            )
        )
    )&
    IF(
        $A21="NG",
        "Natural Gas Henry Hub",
        $A21
    )&
    " "&
    $B21&
    " "&
    $C21&
    " "&
    $F21&
    " "&
    $G21&
    " @ "&
    $H21&
    ",
     "&
    IF(
        ISBLANK(
            $K21
        ),
        IF(
            ISBLANK(
                $O21
            ),
            "LIVE",
            "You "&
            $N21&
            " "&
            IF(
                $A21="NG",
                TEXT(
                    $O21*$G$13,
                    "#,
                    ##0"
                ),
                $O21
            )&
            IF(
                $B21="APO",
                "/mo ",
                IF(
                    $A21="NG",
                    "/MMBtu ",
                    IF(
                        $A21="FO 3.5%",
                        "/kt ",
                        "/kbbl "
                    )
                )
            )&
            IF(
                $A21="NG",
                "Natural Gas Henry Hub",
                $A21
            )&
            " "&
            $C21&
            " "&
            IF(
                $B21="American",
                "Futures ",
                IF(
                    $B21="APO",
                    "Swaps ",
                    IF(
                        $B21="European",
                        IF(
                            $A21="NG",
                            "Penultimate Future",
                            "Swap"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )&
            " @ "&
            TEXT(
                $P21,
                 "#,
                ##0.00##"
            ),
            "You "&
            $I21&
            " "&
            IF(
                $A21="NG",
                TEXT(
                    $J21*$G$13,
                    "#,
                    ##0"
                ),
                $J21
            )&
            IF(
                $B21="APO",
                "/mo ",
                IF(
                    $A21="NG",
                    "/MMBtu ",
                    IF(
                        $A21="FO 3.5%",
                        "/kt ",
                        "/kbbl "
                    )
                )
            )&
            IF(
                $A21="NG",
                "Natural Gas Henry Hub",
                $A21
            )&
            " "&
            $B21&
            " "&
            $C21&
            " "&
            $K21&
            " "&
            $L21&
            " @ "&
            $M21&
            IF(
                ISBLANK(
                    $O21
                ),
                ",
                 LIVE",
                ",
                 You "&
                $N21&
                " "&
                IF(
                    $A21="NG",
                    TEXT(
                        $O21*$G$13,
                        "#,
                        ##0"
                    ),
                    $O21
                )&
                IF(
                    $B21="APO",
                    "/mo ",
                    IF(
                        $A21="NG",
                        "/MMBtu ",
                        IF(
                            $A21 ="FO 3.5%",
                            "/kt ",
                            "/kbbl "
                        )
                    )
                )&
                IF(
                    $A21="NG",
                    "Natural Gas Henry Hub",
                    $A21
                )&
                " "&
                $C21&
                " "&
                IF(
                    $B21="American",
                    "Futures",
                    IF(
                        $B21="APO",
                        "Swaps",
                        IF(
                            $B21="European",
                            IF(
                                $A21="NG",
                                "Penultimate Future",
                                "Swap"
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )&
                " @ "&
                $P21
            )
        )&
        "; "&
        IF(
            $Q21="i",
            "ICE BLOCK,
            ",
            "ClearPort BLOCK,
            "
        )&
        " Thank You"
```

There's probably multiple issues in here. For instance you can see on line 43 the `IF()` formula

```
    IF(
        ISBLANK(
            $K21
        ),
```

Which doesn't have a closing parentheses (nor does it have a `value if false` argument, although that shouldn't throw an error). Or perhaps it does and there is an extra closing parantheses in here where it doesn't belong..

At any rate, this should help you diagnose the problem, and maybe do a more efficient rewrite (or convert to UDF)

Comment: I'm not going to even attempt to check this but bonus points for the attempt; whatever the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt JNevill.  THink it's the best solution i'm going to get in the assistance.  Thanks very much i'll give it a go.

Comment: @JNevill I actually hadn't thought of a UDF.  I think i'll build that out as it would probably present a much cleaner solution and it would be unnoticeable to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Created a UDF rather than using the hideous formula posted above as per JNevill's recommendation.  UDF accepts an range object parameter.  Code below

```
Function BUILDCHATCONFIRM(tradeDataRange As Range) As String

    Dim chatConfirmString As String, firstLegBuySell As String, secondLegBuySell As String, futureLegBuySell As String, iceClearingDesignation As String, cmeClearingDesignation As String, nasdaqClearingDesignation As String, contractMonth As String, productType As String
    Dim nattyGasMultiplier As Long, firstLegQuantity As Long, secondLegQuantity As Long, futureLegQuantity As Long

    nattyGasMultiplier = 10000
    cmeClearingDesignation = "; ClearPort BLOCK, Thank You"
    iceClearingDesignation = "; ICE BLOCK, Thank You"
    nasdaqClearingDesignation = "; NASDAQ BLOCK, Thank you"

    firstLegBuySell = tradeDataRange.Item(4).Value
    secondLegBuySell = tradeDataRange.Item(9).Value
    futureLegBuySell = tradeDataRange.Item(14).Value
    contractMonth = tradeDataRange.Item(3).Value
    productType = tradeDataRange.Item(1).Value
    firstLegQuantity = tradeDataRange.Item(5).Value
    secondLegQuantity = tradeDataRange.Item(10).Value
    futureLegQuantity = tradeDataRange.Item(15).Value

    'Accounts for natty multiplier when building natty confirms
    If productType = "NG" Then

        productType = "Natural Gas Henry Hub"

        firstLegQuantity = firstLegQuantity * nattyGasMultiplier
        secondLegQuantity = secondLegQuantity * nattyGasMultiplier
        futureLegQuantity = futureLegQuantity * nattyGasMultiplier

    End If

    'Builds future leg if just a futures trade or a blank cell
    If Len(firstLegBuySell) = 0 Then

        If Len(futureLegBuySell) = 0 Then

            chatConfirmString = "Nothing"

            GoTo SkipToEnd

        Else

            If Application.Caller.Column = 20 Then

                If futureLegBuySell = "Buy" Or futureLegBuySell = "buy" Then

                    futureLegBuySell = "Sell"

                Else

                    futureLegBuySell = "Buy"

                End If

            End If

            chatConfirmString = "You " & futureLegBuySell & " " & Format(futureLegQuantity, "#,#00") & DetermineProductMeasurementType(productType, tradeDataRange.Item(2).Value, contractMonth) & " " & productType & " " & contractMonth & " " & DetermineFuturesType(productType, tradeDataRange.Item(2).Value) & " @ " & Format(tradeDataRange.Item(16).Value, "#,#00.00##")

        End If

    'Builds option and subsequent hedge confirms detected by a Len > 0 first buy/sell leg
    Else

        If Application.Caller.Column = 20 Then Call ChangeDirectionForSellSide(firstLegBuySell, secondLegBuySell, futureLegBuySell)

        'First option leg built
        chatConfirmString = "You " & firstLegBuySell & " " & Format(firstLegQuantity, "#,#00") & DetermineProductMeasurementType(productType, tradeDataRange.Item(2).Value, contractMonth) & " " & productType & " " & tradeDataRange.Item(2).Value & " " & contractMonth & " " & tradeDataRange.Item(6).Value & " " & tradeDataRange.Item(7).Value & " @ " & Format(tradeDataRange.Item(8).Value, "###.00##")

        'tests for existence and builds second option leg
        If Len(secondLegBuySell) <> 0 Then

            chatConfirmString = chatConfirmString & ", You " & secondLegBuySell & " " & Format(secondLegQuantity, "#,#00") & DetermineProductMeasurementType(productType, tradeDataRange.Item(2).Value, contractMonth) & " " & productType & " " & tradeDataRange.Item(2).Value & " " & contractMonth & " " & Format(tradeDataRange.Item(11).Value, "#,##0.00##") & " " & tradeDataRange.Item(12).Value & " @ " & Format(tradeDataRange.Item(13).Value, "###.00##")

        Else

            'Do nothing move on to futures leg

        End If

        'Builds futures leg
        If Len(futureLegBuySell) <> 0 Then

            chatConfirmString = chatConfirmString & ", You " & futureLegBuySell & " " & Format(futureLegQuantity, "#,#00") & DetermineProductMeasurementType(productType, tradeDataRange.Item(2).Value, contractMonth) & " " & productType & " " & contractMonth & " " & DetermineFuturesType(productType, tradeDataRange.Item(2).Value) & " @ " & Format(tradeDataRange.Item(16).Value, "#,##0.00##")

        Else

            chatConfirmString = chatConfirmString & ", LIVE"

        End If

    End If


    'determines clearing designation string closure
    Select Case chatConfirmString

        Case "Nothing"

            'Do nothing pass "nothing" string through

        Case Else

            If tradeDataRange.Item(17).Value = "c" Or tradeDataRange.Item(17).Value = "C" Then

                chatConfirmString = chatConfirmString & cmeClearingDesignation

            ElseIf tradeDataRange.Item(17).Value = "i" Or tradeDataRange.Item(17).Value = "I" Then

                chatConfirmString = chatConfirmString & iceClearingDesignation

            ElseIf tradeDataRange.Item(17).Value = "n" Or tradeDataRange.Item(17).Value = "N" Then

                chatConfirmString = chatConfirmString & nasdaqClearingDesignation

            Else

                chatConfirmString = chatConfirmString & cmeClearingDesignation

            End If

    End Select

SkipToEnd:

    BUILDCHATCONFIRM = chatConfirmString

End Function

Function DetermineProductMeasurementType(ByVal productType As String, ByVal assetType As String, ByVal assetTerm As String) As String

    'Determines if it is a multimonth structure
    If InStr(1, assetTerm, "-") > 0 Or assetType = "APO" Then

        DetermineProductMeasurementType = "/mo"

        GoTo SkipToEndDetermineProduct

    ElseIf Left(assetTerm, 1) = "Q" And Len(assetTerm) = 4 Then

        DetermineProductMeasurementType = "/mo"

        GoTo SkipToEndDetermineProduct

    End If

    'Analysis of Type for single month contracts
    If assetType = "American" Or assetType = "European" And productType <> "Natural Gas Henry Hub" And productType <> "FO 3.5%" Then

        DetermineProductMeasurementType = "/kbbl"

    ElseIf assetType = "American" Or assetType = "European" And productType = "Natural Gas Henry Hub" Then

        DetermineProductMeasurementType = "/MMBtu"

    ElseIf productType = "FO 3.5%" Then

        DetermineProductMeasurementType = "/kt"

    Else

        DetermineProductMeasurementType = "/kbbl"

    End If

SkipToEndDetermineProduct:

End Function

Function DetermineFuturesType(ByVal productType As String, ByVal optionType As String) As String
'Determines futures type by option type and expiry

    Select Case optionType

        Case "American"

            DetermineFuturesType = "Futures"

        Case "APO"

            DetermineFuturesType = "Swaps"

        Case "European"

            If productType = "Natural Gas Henry Hub" Then

                DetermineFuturesType = "Penultimate Futures"

            Else

                DetermineFuturesType = "Swaps"

            End If

        Case Else

            DetermineFuturesType = "Futures"

    End Select

End Function

Sub ChangeDirectionForSellSide(ByRef firstBuySellLeg As String, ByRef secondBuySellLeg As String, ByRef futureBuySellLeg As String)
    'Changes direction of buy/sell legs for sell side column

    If firstBuySellLeg = "Buy" Or firstBuySellLeg = "buy" Then

        firstBuySellLeg = "Sell"

    ElseIf firstBuySellLeg = "Sell" Or firstBuySellLeg = "sell" Then

        firstBuySellLeg = "Buy"

    Else

        'Do nothing

    End If

    If secondBuySellLeg = "Buy" Or secondBuySellLeg = "buy" Then

        secondBuySellLeg = "Sell"

    ElseIf secondBuySellLeg = "Sell" Or secondBuySellLeg = "sell" Then

        secondBuySellLeg = "Buy"

    Else

        'Do nothing

    End If

    If futureBuySellLeg = "Buy" Or futureBuySellLeg = "buy" Then

        futureBuySellLeg = "Sell"

    ElseIf futureBuySellLeg = "Sell" Or futureBuySellLeg = "sell" Then

        futureBuySellLeg = "Buy"

    Else

        'Do Nothing

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh! That looks much more friendly!